# PHP Error - Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/bridgesh/public_html/includes/functions/html_output.php on line 45

From the following lines of code:

```
44. while ($val = current($new_get)){
45.     if($val==end(array_reverse ($new_get)) )$new_getstr.='?'.key($new_get).'='.$val;
46.     else $new_getstr.='&amp;'.key($new_get).'='.$val;
47.     next($new_get);     
48. }
```

I've read through similar questions & answers on the subject here, but cannot figure out how to break the line down correctly.

Comment: _“but cannot figure out how to break the line down correctly”_ – to actually break it down into multiple lines, so that you can find out which of the statements used there actually causes the error, would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

`end` works on a reference to an array, so it expects a variable, that contains an array
`array_reverse ($new_get)` however is not a variable, but a function call
You have to do:

```
   $reversed = array_reverse ($new_get)
   if($val==end($reversed) )$new_getstr.='?'.key($new_get).'='.$val;
```

Comment: Brilliant Darkhazer, that worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$new_getstr = http_build_query($new_get);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/http-build-query)

Comment: I'd love to see a reason for downvoting this answer.

Comment: I didn't do this, but it's obviously because you missed an explanation.